# trac svn python bindings messed up rebuild python

Tags: centos, python, trac

My trac and svn used to work it still does if i click on the links many times. How ever it complaines of he followign and i am not sure what to do i have followed http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion and http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion but nothings changed. I am using centos 5, svn 1.6, trac 0.10.4, python 2.4.3

```
2013-11-29 14:24:14,458 Trac[main] ERROR: Unsupported version control system "svn". Check that the Python bindings for "svn" are correctly installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 406, in dispatch_request
    dispatcher.dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 191, in dispatch
    chosen_handler = self._pre_process_request(req, chosen_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 263, in _pre_process_request
    chosen_handler = f.pre_process_request(req, chosen_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 73, in pre_process_request
    self.get_repository(req.authname).sync()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 91, in get_repository
    raise TracError('Unsupported version control system "%s". '
TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn". Check that the Python bindings for "svn" are correctly installed.
2013-11-29 14:24:15,090 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading file plugin ez_setup from /usr/share/trac/plugins/ez_setup.py
2013-11-29 14:24:15,154 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,286 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.query from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,345 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.attachment from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,345 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_fs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,564 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.mimeview.enscript from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,627 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.patch from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,629 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.txtl from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,643 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.txtl because it requires "textile>=2.0"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,643 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.admin.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,644 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.admin.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:15,682 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.web.session from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,683 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,684 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.ticket.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:15,685 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.rst from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,699 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.rst because it requires "docutils>=0.3"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,699 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.postgres from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,701 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,734 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.timeline from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,735 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.timeline from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named timeline.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:15,736 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.pygments from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,749 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.pygments because it requires "Pygments>=0.6"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,750 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,750 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.wiki.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:15,751 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.about from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,752 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.about from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named about
2013-11-29 14:24:15,752 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.ticket.commit_updater from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,758 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.ticket.commit_updater from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/ticket/commit_updater.py", line 48, in ?
ImportError: No module named compat
2013-11-29 14:24:15,759 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.interwiki from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,762 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.roadmap from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,765 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_prop from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,766 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_prop from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named svn_prop
2013-11-29 14:24:15,766 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.silvercity from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,779 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.silvercity because it requires "SilverCity>=0.9.4"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,779 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.macros from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,780 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.sqlite from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,790 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.ticket.deleter from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,045 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.ticket.deleter from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/ticket/deleter.py", line 22, in ?
ImportError: No module named translation
2013-11-29 14:24:16,046 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,054 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.mimeview.php from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,055 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.web.auth from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,090 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.web_api from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,091 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.wiki.web_api from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named web_api
2013-11-29 14:24:16,092 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.admin.console from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,092 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.admin.console from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin.console
2013-11-29 14:24:16,093 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.mysql from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,094 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.perm.authz_policy from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,096 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.perm.authz_policy from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/perm/authz_policy.py", line 23, in ?
ImportError: cannot import name IPermissionPolicy
2013-11-29 14:24:16,097 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_authz from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,097 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,098 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.versioncontrol.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:16,098 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.search from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,099 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.search from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named search.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:16,099 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,100 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.prefs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,101 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.prefs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named prefs.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:16,101 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.report from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
```

I have tried downloading and re-installing trac 0.10.4 and I also noticed the following problem, I cannot create any trac projects either

```
[root@hero trac]# trac-admin nagios initenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/trac-admin", line 21, in ?
    from trac.scripts.admin import run
ImportError: No module named scripts.admin
```

29th november is when all this happened, only 3 packages where updated.

```
[root@hero trac]# rpm -qa --queryformat '%{installtime} (%{installtime:date}) %{name}\n' | sort -n | tail -20
1272376205 (Tue 27 Apr 2010 02:50:05 PM BST) perl-Digest-SHA
1272376206 (Tue 27 Apr 2010 02:50:06 PM BST) perl-Net-DNS
1272376367 (Tue 27 Apr 2010 02:52:47 PM BST) perl-Net-IMAP-Simple
1297437326 (Fri 11 Feb 2011 03:15:26 PM GMT) rsync
1303313671 (Wed 20 Apr 2011 04:34:31 PM BST) bacula-libs
1303313686 (Wed 20 Apr 2011 04:34:46 PM BST) bacula-client
1319625083 (Wed 26 Oct 2011 11:31:23 AM BST) nano
1320596688 (Sun 06 Nov 2011 04:24:48 PM GMT) libsmbclient
1320596692 (Sun 06 Nov 2011 04:24:52 PM GMT) samba-common
1320596694 (Sun 06 Nov 2011 04:24:54 PM GMT) perl-Convert-ASN1
1320596695 (Sun 06 Nov 2011 04:24:55 PM GMT) samba-client
1320596697 (Sun 06 Nov 2011 04:24:57 PM GMT) samba
1360917828 (Fri 15 Feb 2013 08:43:48 AM GMT) which
1380191389 (Thu 26 Sep 2013 11:29:49 AM BST) httperf
1380798707 (Thu 03 Oct 2013 12:11:47 PM BST) libssh2
1380798733 (Thu 03 Oct 2013 12:12:13 PM BST) libssh2-devel
1380799094 (Thu 03 Oct 2013 12:18:14 PM BST) php-pear
1385728355 (Fri 29 Nov 2013 12:32:35 PM GMT) neon
1385728360 (Fri 29 Nov 2013 12:32:40 PM GMT) subversion
1385728366 (Fri 29 Nov 2013 12:32:46 PM GMT) mod_dav_svn
```

In theory if i remove the dir `/usr/share/trac` and `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/` and re-install trac 0.10.4 should it not work? I have tried this and it does not.

I have now done the following which has fixed issue of allowing me to create trac projects, however I cannot get into trac using browser.

```
[root@hero trac]# easy_install -m trac
Searching for trac
Best match: Trac 0.12
Processing Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Removing Trac 0.12 from easy-install.pth file
Installing trac-admin script to /usr/bin
Installing tracd script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg

Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:

    pkg_resources.require("Trac")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("Trac==0.12")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("Trac>=0.12")  # this version or higher

Processing dependencies for trac
Finished processing dependencies for trac
```

The error I receive is

```
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend: Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend:   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 287, in HandlerDispatch\n    log=debug), referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend:   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 461, in import_module\n    f, p, d = imp.find_module(parts[i], path), referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend: ImportError: No module named trac, referer: http://hero/trac/
```

Comment: Have you recently run `yum update` on the system? Most likely your install of Python changed or one it's modules, or the libraries that create bindings between SVN and Python.

Comment: yes i have, i think subversion was updated

Comment: That's the problem, most likely. You can remove it and then try installing the older version.

Comment: there was a list of updates that installed as well how would i revert back to them? i don't know what they was

Comment: `$ rpm -qa --queryformat '%{installtime} (%{installtime:date}) %{name}\n' | sort -n | tail -10` will show you the last 10 packages installed. You can adjust the `tail -10` to get more by changing `-10` to `-20`, for eg.

Comment: @slm updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `/usr/share/trac` and `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/`. downlaoded v 0.10.4 and re-installed. Not sure why the 1st time it did not work, but this solved my problem and successfully restored trac.